# How to inject pen inputs from a digitiser using InjectTouchInput() with PT_PEN on Windows 10

Tags: c++, windows-10, touch, pen

I am using the `InjectTouchInput()` API on Windows 10 to inject touch events from a separate digitiser. That works well (multi-touch etc.). There are quite a few examples out there of using the API for that, i.e. using a pointer type of `PT_TOUCH`, including one [from Microsoft](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Touch-Injection-Sample-444d9bf7), so it wasn't too difficult to customise them to my needs.

However, I have not found any example of using other pointer types, especially `PT_PEN` - which I need when the digitiser gives me pen inputs. (I'd also be interested in `PT_MOUSE`, mainly to avoid having to use `SendInput()` or `mouse_event()`.)

Whenever I call `InjectTouchInput()` with `PT_PEN`, it fails with `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER`. I've tried quite a few combinations of fields to set, but nothing (so far) works. The MSDN documentation doesn't describe what to do for `PT_PEN` (it doesn't describe much for `PT_TOUCH`, but at least there's one sample), so it's quite difficult to know what fields **should** be set, which ones **should** be ignored, any specific sequence of operations, etc. I've been scouring the net, but couldn't find any example of `PT_PEN` use.

Does anybody have sample code or know where to find any, knowledge of where useful documentation is located, or knows how `InjectTouchInput()` is supposed to be used for `PT_PEN` (and `PT_MOUSE`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `InjectTouchInput()` is indeed only for touch inputs - not pen, mouse, or generic pointer.

You might say that it's obvious, since you pass an array of `POINTER_TOUCH_INFO` entries to the API, but confusion arises because the documentation for `POINTER_TOUCH_INFO` (and all subsequent documentation) is describing the contents mostly as seen from someone who interprets contents he is given, and not content he is trying to set, **and** `POINTER_INFO` (the first element in `POINTER_TOUCH_INFO`) can specify a pointer type of `PT_POINTER`, `PT_TOUCH`, `PT_PEN`, `PT_MOUSE`, or `PT_TOUCHPAD`, so it feels kinda natural to think "*wait, I can* inject *all these different types of pointers!*"

Of course, all the pointer types, despite having `POINTER_INFO` in common, takes slightly different parameters. For instance, there is `orientation` and `pressure` for `PT_TOUCH` (in `POINTER_TOUCH_INFO`), but `tiltX`, `tiltY`, `rotation`, and `pressure` for `PT_PEN` (in `POINTER_PEN_INFO`); but it would be easy to determine which info is relevant given that the pointer type is always the first field in the structures.

Can `InjectTouchInput()` take `POINTER_PEN_INFO` entries instead of  `POINTER_TOUCH_INFO` ones? No, it can't - I tried, just in case it would work.

It seems like a missed opportunity by Microsoft to make the API more generic from the start and accept all the supported types of pointers, rather than be limited to touch inputs. At the very least, pen injection should have been straightforward, given that there is a `POINTER_PEN_INFO` structure (I haven't found structures for the other pointer types besides `POINTER_TOUCH_INFO`).

Half-way through [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/05d741e4-4c2a-4710-b927-83e88bcf4f61/is-it-possible-to-make-touch-input-appear-as-pen-input?forum=tabletandtouch) from 2014 is the mention that "*there is no [...] API for pen injection*", and things haven't improved since then, so a driver for pen injection is still required. Having said that, the Windows UI Automation API can apparently inject all pointer types (and a game pad to boot), but that's only supported from Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (and I haven't tried it).

Answer (score 1):

We can implement pen input injection with [InputInjector.InjectPenInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.input.preview.injection)

And there is no public apis in win32 for pen injection. If your system is Windows 10, version 1809, [InjectSyntheticPointerInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-injectsyntheticpointerinput) can be used.

Comment: That's for UWP and C# - I did ask for C++. When will the Win32 equivalent for desktop development become available? Or is there now an equivalent? I've left that field, so I don't need an answer, but somebody else might be interested.

Comment: Update in the main thread. There is no public apis before win10 1809.

Comment: Thanks for the info, and sorry for the late follow-up.